# While upgrading react-native from 0.68 to 0.69 , getting this error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

ERROR:  Invariant Violation: ViewPropTypes has been removed from React Native. Migrate to ViewPropTypes exported from 'deprecated-react-native-prop-types'.
ERROR:  Invariant Violation: Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module (calling runApplication). A frequent cause of the error is that the application entry file path is incorrect.
This can also happen when the JS bundle is corrupt or there is an early initialization error when loading React Native.
ERROR  Invariant Violation: Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module (calling runApplication). A frequent cause of the error is that the application entry file path is incorrect.
This can also happen when the JS bundle is corrupt or there is an early initialization error when loading React Native.

I have replace these functions with the below lines in **node_modules/react-native/index.js**

```
// Deprecated Prop Types
get ColorPropType(): $FlowFixMe {
  console.warn('');
  return require('deprecated-react-native-prop-types').ColorPropType;
},

get EdgeInsetsPropType(): $FlowFixMe {
  console.warn('');
  return require('deprecated-react-native-prop-types').EdgeInsetsPropType;
},

get PointPropType(): $FlowFixMe {
  console.warn('');
  return require('deprecated-react-native-prop-types').PointPropType;
},

get ViewPropTypes(): $FlowFixMe {
  console.warn('');
  return require('deprecated-react-native-prop-types').ViewPropTypes;
},
```

but got this error:

TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_reactNative.Text.propTypes.style')

Is there any other method to resolve this error without changing node modules codes or without using patch

Answer (score 2):

Install the plugin

```
npm install --save-dev babel-plugin-module-resolver deprecated-react-native-prop-types
```